# $\mathbb Z_n$ as $\mathbb Z[i]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> I am trying to find all $n$ such that $\mathbb Z_n$ is a $\mathbb Z[i]$-module, where $\mathbb Z[i]$ is the ring of Gaussian integers.

I proved that any $\mathbb Z[i]$-module $M$ is just an Abelian group with hommomrphism $\psi:M\rightarrow M$ and $\psi^2=-I_M$ .

Comment: Use the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID.

Comment: What is theorem ? Could you hint me for a link or a nice explanation for it ?

Comment: Ah, never mind, lhf's answer is easier. The argument I had in mind tells you more generally which finite abelian groups can have the structure of a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $M=\mathbb Z/n$ as a group is cyclic generated by $1$, an endomorphism $\psi:M\rightarrow M$ is determined by $\psi(1)$.
If $\psi^2=-I_M$, then $a^2=-1$ in $M$.

Thus, you're looking for all $n$ such that there is $a\in \mathbb Z$ such that $a^2 \equiv -1 \bmod n$.

For instance, when $n$ is prime, this means that $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. But there are [other solutions](https://oeis.org/A008784).

The full answer is the numbers $n$ whose prime divisors are all congruent to $1$ mod $4$, with the exception of at most a single factor of $2$.